# ActiveRecord custom attributes used in rails 3 not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have following code working in rails 3.2:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_details()
    cart_obj = Cart.first
    cart_obj["custom"] = 1 #Here *custom* is not the column in database
  end
end
```

And i can access the column **custom** from the cart_obj object whenever we require.

But we are planning to upgrade to rails 4 and its not working there. Is there any work around for it except using attr_accessor??

Comment: Use `write_attribute`.

Comment: Thanks @MarekLipka  Any example? Also please go through below comment.

Comment: Example: `cart_obj.write_attribute('custom', 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails 4, use attr_accessor:

If you have additional instance data you don't need to persist (i.e. it's not a database column), you could then use attr_accessor to save yourself a few lines of code.

```
class cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor  :custom

  def self.get_details
    cart_obj = Cart.first
    cart_obj.custom = whatever 
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay for quick reply. But I am looking some other work around than using attr_accesor.

Comment: What's the purpose, I will do if anything I could. :)

Comment: We have a large project in rails 3.2 and we want to upgrade it to rails 4.2. So we have huge occurrence of custom attributes as I mentioned in example code. If we start using it as attr_accessor then it will take too much time which won't be feasible. So initially we would like to somehow get it in working condition and then keep improving the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like monkey patching is your way to go:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def [](key)
    return super(key) if self.class.column_names.include?(key.to_sym)
    self.class.send :attr_accessor, key.to_sym unless self.class.instance_variable_defined?("@#{key}".to_sym)
    self.instance_variable_get("@#{key}".to_sym)
  end

  def []=(key, val)
    return super(key, val) if self.class.column_names.include?(key.to_sym)
    self.class.send :attr_accessor, key.to_sym unless self.class.instance_variable_defined?("@#{key}".to_sym)
    self.instance_variable_set("@#{key}".to_sym, val)
  end
end
```

Or if you'd like to have it as a concern:

```
module MemoryStorage
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  def [](key)
    return super(key) if self.class.column_names.include?(key.to_sym)
    self.class.send :attr_accessor, key.to_sym unless self.class.instance_variable_defined?("@#{key}".to_sym)
    self.instance_variable_get("@#{key}".to_sym)
  end

  def []=(key, val)
    return super(key, val) if self.class.column_names.include?(key.to_sym)
    self.class.send :attr_accessor, key.to_sym unless self.class.instance_variable_defined?("@#{key}".to_sym)
    self.instance_variable_set("@#{key}".to_sym, val)
  end
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MemoryStorage

  def self.get_details()
    cart_obj = Cart.first
    cart_obj.db_column = 'direct DB access'
    cart_obj["custom"] = 'access to "in-memory" column'
  end
end
```